# How to wrap text in ListView's TextCell?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to wrap text in ListView's TextCell? I tried setting `HasUnevenRows` to `True` but that didn't help.

Comment: I don't think you can without either writing a `Custom Renderer` for it or create your own customised cell

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot with Xamarin's 'out-of-the-box' TextCell features.  BUT, you should be able to create a ViewCell and leverage the [LineBreakMode](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Label.LineBreakMode/) property of Label to accomplish word wrapping.  Something like this perhaps:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="My TextCell Text" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                    <Label Text="My TextCell Detail" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```